# What analysis to use with a categorical DV and a within subjects design?

Tags: categorical-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Giving more details to my last post: I'm very lost and don't know which tests to use or how to enter data in SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30275/giving-more-details-to-my-last-post-im-very-lost-and-dont-know-which-tests-to)

I conducted an experiment using a within subjects design and 2x2 categorical fixed factors design with a categorical DV (every subject was in every condition). I have no idea what test to use.

Thanks for your help,
Emily

Comment: I don't either.  State your objective and then we can figure this out. It may be that you want to see if the distribution of subject responses varies as the values of the factors change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should mention that my DV is dichotomous. From doing more research online on this site and others, I think I am going to use a mixed model ANOVA with my two IV's as fixed effects and the subjects as a random effect. I read the Lunney article and it seems like I can use ANOVA even with my dichotomous DV. Each condition has 3 items and I have 37 subjects (there might be one or two missing values but it's not major). Any thoughts?